# JSON_REMOVE object in MySQL

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I am trying to delete objects from my JSON array in MySQL.

I have a table called cart with two fields `quote_id` type `int` and `items` type `json` with the following row stored inside MySQL

quote_id: 0

items:

`[ 
   { 
      "a":42,
      "b":"test4"
   },
   { 
      "a":32,
      "b":"test3"
   }
]`

I am trying to create a query which would delete json objects from the json array. For example every 

`{ 
      "a":32,
      "b":"test3"
   }`

I have tried many queries. First I ended up with this:

```
UPDATE cart
SET items = IFNULL(JSON_REMOVE(items, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(items, 'one', 'test3'))), items)
WHERE quote_id = 13392;
```

However it just deletes "b":"test3" from the second object and left the "a":32 in it and I need a query that would find the whole object and would delete it.

This is my second query:

```
UPDATE cart
SET items = IFNULL(JSON_REMOVE(items, JSON_SEARCH(items, 'one', CAST('{"a": 32, "b": "test3"}' AS JSON))), items)
WHERE quote_id = 13392;
```

However I don't think the search on it works. I tried it without using the CAST()AS JSON, however it still did not work.

As I said I am pretty sure the problem is with the `JSON_SEARCH`, but maybe someone has the solution?

Thank you!

Comment: What is your datatype of that field?

Comment: Which one, info? It's JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JSON_SEARCH` returns the path of the property, not the path to the object itself.

So you can use the following solution to get the object path with `SUBSTR`:

```
SELECT JSON_REMOVE(items, 
    SUBSTR(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(items, 'one', 'test3')), 1, LOCATE('.', JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(items, 'one', 'test3')))-1)
) FROM cart
```

You can also use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to get the object path:

```
SELECT JSON_REMOVE(items, REGEXP_SUBSTR(JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(items, 'one', 'test3')), '^\\$\\[[0-9]+\\]'))
FROM cart
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=63b5178151bfaadf9983a69ca05d3bef)